# grafana: See full list of metrics when hovering

Tags: grafana

Grafana has a feature where hovering over a graph shows a list of each metric and its value at that point. The problem I'm having is that my graph has many metrics and the list is not scrollable. This means that when hovering, I can only see the first ~40 metrics even though my graph has ~150 metrics.

Perhaps the list is scrollable, but when I move my mouse toward it, it goes away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Display Styles -> Tooltip -> Uncheck "All Series"

This will allow you to hover over a specific metric to see its value. I believe "All Series" is checked by default.

Comment: I haven't decided if this is a solution for me, but it is better than what I have so +1

Comment: I had this problem with stacked bar charts. Tooltips show values for all the parts of the bar even those not visible for this exact bar. Choosing *All* allow you to decide the ordering based on value and you get the ones with value on top; which is great.